# Showing function defined on $\text{Frac}(R)$ is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $f : R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism where $R, S$ are integral domains.

I want to show that $\varphi : \text{Frac}(R) \to \text{Frac}(S)$ defined by $r/1 \mapsto f(r)/1$ is a ring homomorphism.

What I don't understand is how does defining the function on $r/1$ define it for an arbitrary element $r/u$?

Some thoughts: If $\varphi$ is in fact a ring homomorphism, then we would have $$\varphi(r/u) = \varphi\big( (r/1) \cdot (1/u) \big) = \varphi \big( (r/1) \cdot (u/1)^{-1}\big) = \varphi(r/1) \cdot \varphi\big( (u/1)^{-1} \big) = \cdots = f(r)/f(u).$$ So this is what I would expect to happen to a general element of $\text{Frac}(R)$. But I'm not seeing how to figure this out before I know that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism? I need to know what $\varphi$ does to an arbitrary element, to show it's a homomorphism.

Comment: As you guessed, you miss some hipotesis

Comment: Typically $\phi(r/u)=f(r)f(u)^{-1}$ is the definition.

Comment: Okay! Thanks. I got this from Rotman's book on homological algebra, and it only defines it on $r/1$. Is there any way we can show that this definition isn't sufficient?

Comment: It is possible only if $f$ is injective.

Comment: @Bernard, is the following a counterexample: $f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_2$ defined by $z \mapsto z \pmod 2$? The problem arises when we try to calculate the value of $2/3 = 4/6 = (4/1) \cdot (6/1)^{-1}$, we can't divide by zero. Correct?

Comment: Actually waht  is always defined is a *module*-homorphism from $K$ to the module of fractions $S\otimes_R K$, through whih $K\to S$ should factor if it were defined. In the case you mention this module of fractions is $0$, and we require a ring homomorphism to map $1$ to $1$ (and thus a field homomorphism to be $1$ to $1$!)